# AttributeError: 'ec2.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'send_command'

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have tried to create user credential in AWS EC2 Windows Instance using Boto3 AWS-RunPowerShellScript. But when i trying to run this below code, getting error "AttributeError: 'ec2.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'send_command'".

````
import boto3
import os
import subprocess

ssm_client = boto3.resource('ec2',aws_access_key_id='xxxxxx',aws_secret_access_key='yyyyy', region_name='us-west-2')

session = boto3.Session (profile_name='exampleaws')

response = ssm_client.send_command(
             InstanceIds=[
                "i-xxxxxx" # use instance id on which you want to execute, even multiple is allowd
                     ],
             DocumentName="AWS-RunPowerShellScript",
             Parameters={
                'commands':[
                     'New-LocalUser "Latchu" -Password "ABCD123" -FullName "LakshmiNarayanan" -Description "User-Details'
                       ]
                   },
             )
command_id = response['Command']['CommandId']
output = ssm_client.get_command_invocation(
      CommandId=command_id,
      InstanceId='i-xxxxxx',
    )
print(output)```
````

Comment: Hi. I've noticed that you have a lot of questions and most of them have answers provided. However, you have not accepted any of them. It is good practice to accepted good answers as it helps others with same/similar problems. If correct answers are not accepted, it prompts people to make duplicate question on a false assumption that existing answers to your questions are not helpful.

Comment: ok sure. hereafter i won't do like that. If not solved my issue with provided answers, then what should i do?

Comment: You would normally make a comment why an answer does not solve the issue. This way the person who answered has a chance to modify it, and others can provide more helpful answers  based on the comment.

Comment: Ok. i will do without fail. many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ssm_client` is incorrect as [send_command](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.send_command) is property of `ssm`, not `ec2`. Thus, it should be:

```
ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm', aws_access_key_id='xxxxxx', aws_secret_access_key='yyyyy', region_name='us-west-2')
```

Also your `session` is not used at all. There still could be other errors which are not apparent yet.

Comment: Its running without error.  i getting below output. But users not created in Windows Ec2 instance.

Comment: @LakshminarayananS This must be something related to your `RunPowerShellScript`. Sadly, I don't know how to fix that. My answer was related to the original problem posted regarding "AttributeError: 'ec2.ServiceResource' ".

Comment: Output looks like fine, but user not created in EC2 instance.     HTTPStatusCode': 200

Comment: I will check my Powershell script and i will post here once its solved

Comment: @LakshminarayananS You can go to SSM Console, and locate the execution of your command. Usually it will have some error messages that can help.

Comment: Yes,i will look at AWS SSM console

Comment: I executed powershell command on AWS SSM console. Its running successfully. But user not created in AWS EC2 instance. bro

Comment: I think my powershell command is wrong. i would like to pass user name and password as single powershell command

Comment: Finally script executed fine with user creation, i have used powershell command : net user username "Password" /ADD .